# Subview of dynamic height in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

This question is w.r.t xib and old style of showing custom `CellView`'s in `UITableView`. I do have `autolayouts` in my views.

I have a `DynamicSubView` (dynamic height) of type `UIView` which I want to reuse in `UITableViewCell`. For this I have tried 2 things,

- Adding `DynamicSubview` as `[cell.contentView addSubview:myDynamicView]`
- Added a `UIView` inside `cell.xib`'s contentView with constraint `0-0-0-0` on all `Left-Top-Right-Bottom`. And a height as `NSLayoutConstraint` which I am calulating & changing at runtime. And setted `identity inspector` of that view to `DynamicSubview`.

In `MyCell.m` class, I have added created a object of `DynamicSubView` class in `awakeFromNib` & in `layoutSubView` method, I am calculating dynamic height of `DynamicSubView`.

I tried adding height related code in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but it goes in infinite-loop for the very first time when table loads.

The problem is the cells are getting overlaped. Should I create an array of height values and reload again. Any better solution to reload the cell again with proper height.

Code In `MyCell` class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.myDynamicView = (DynamicSubView *)self.myContainerView;
    [self.myDynamicView setUpView:YES];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.myDynamicView doSomething];
    self.c_height.constant = [self.myDynamicView getHeightOfDynamicSubview];

    //CGRect cellFrame = self.contentView.frame;
    //self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(cellFrame.origin.x, cellFrame.origin.y, cellFrame.size.width, self.c_height.constant);
    self.cellHeight = self.c_height.constant;
 }
```

Comment: height depends upon? some string some image what?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the LayoutSubiew() inside the tableViewCell, you can you the following methods in your view controller

**SWIFT**

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 (Let's say minimum height of your tableViewCell is 100)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
 {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }